# Creating MimeMessage object cause signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6

Tags: android, xamarin, mailkit

I'm trying to write email service in my Xamarin.Android app. I'm using MailKit and MimeKit. In my Core project I have IEmailService, in Dorid project it is implemented. It is registered. So in implementation I'm creating MimeMessage object to perform my mail like this:

```
public void Send(string from, string to, string subject, string body)
    {
        var message = new MimeMessage();
        message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(from));
        message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress(to));
        message.Subject = subject;
        message.Body = new TextPart("plain")
        {
            Text = body
        };

        using (var client = new SmtpClient())
        {
            client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true;

            client.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587, false);
            client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");
            client.Authenticate("account@gmail.com", "password");

            client.Send(message);
            client.Disconnect(true);
        }
    }
```

but this cause crash.
I'm pretty sure is fault of this line: var message = new MimeMessage();
Except that, attempt to creating instance of MimeMessage in another place in code e.g. in Activity cusing this same error, also like MailboxAddress. SmtpClient doesn't make any trouble.

Comment: Submit a bug report to Xamarin. You should not be getting a SIGABORT in the runtime. You can’t debug that.

Comment: Turns out the bug is fixed in an upcoming service release of Xamarin. Someone else that reported this bug to me got a prerelease of the fix and it worked for him.

Comment: I've just been told the fix will be released tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks for the info mate.